# Loadfile without polluting global environment

Tags: lua, lua-loadfile

How can I load a file of lua tables and variables without polluting the global environment? Since doing a loadfile and running it just loads everything in the global space and may overwrite something else which I don't want.

Comment: Are you using lua 5.2 or 5.1?

Comment: Found it:

`x = loadfile("myfile.lua")`
`setfenv(x,env)`
`x() -- all global accesses would go to env rather then _G`

Comment: Exactly. You seem to be in 5.1 . You should answer yourself and mark your answer as correct, so it doesn't appear "unanswered", but you don't have the rep for that. :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Lua 5.1 and without much error handling you could do this:

```
-- load and run a script in the provided environment
-- returns the modified environment table
function run(scriptfile)
    local env = setmetatable({}, {__index=_G})
    assert(pcall(setfenv(assert(loadfile(scriptfile)), env)))
    setmetatable(env, nil)
    return env
end
```

The first line creates an empty environment table that can see all existing globals, but which cannot trivially change them since they are visible only by proxy through the `__index` metamethod. Any globals the script creates would be stored in `env`, which is returned. This will work well for simple scripts that just set a bunch of configuration parameters, and which might need to call simple safe functions to set them based on conditions at run time.

Note that making the globals visible to the script is a convenience. Although the globals cannot be modified from the script in the obvious way, `_G` is a global variable that contains a reference to the global environment (containing `_G._G`, `_G._G._G`, etc...) and `_G` can be modified from the script which could lead to further issues.

So rather than using `_G` for the index, it would be much better to construct a table that contains only functions known to be safe and known to be needed by your script's author.

A complete solution would be to run the script in a sandbox, and possibly further protected to prevent accidental (or deliberate) denial of service or worse. [Sandboxes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) are covered in more detail at the Lua User's Wiki. The topic is deeper than it seems at first glance, but as long as your users are trusted to be non-malicious then practical solutions are straightforward.

Lua 5.2 changes things a little bit by eliminating `setfenv()` in favor of a new parameter to `load()`. Details are also in the wiki page.

Comment: One way to work around modifying `_G` is to set `_G` to something else in the environment: `local env = setmetatable({_G=false}, {__index=_G})`

Comment: Actually, I realized that it is really easy to break in the script: `_G=nil; _G.print=nil`. So something like this would be needed: `local env = setmetatable({}, {__index=function(t,k) if k=='_G' then return nil else return _G[k] end})`

Comment: One key idea expressed in the wiki page that I didn't bring up in my answer is to use a whitelist of functions that are carefully selected as safe and needed *rather* than allowing _G or any other globally known module table to leak into the script's environment. Its far safer to let `string.find` into the environment than `string` itself, for instance. That said, the answer as I gave it is quite practical for config files of small non-secure utilities.

Comment: Missing a close paren in line 2?

Comment: @RobertLamb, And here I swore I copied and pasted from working code.... fixed, thanks.

Comment: I'm having an issue when I try this solution. It works fine when run at first, but let's say `env` is returned with a function `env.greet()` that prints `hi` when run. Including the `setmetatable(env, nil)` line means that when `env.greet()` is run, it has no access to the print function. `attempt to index global 'print' (a nil value)`. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **dofile()** version of *RBerteig's* answer where you supply the environment and the result, if any, is returned (I tried to do this as a comment, but couldn't figure out to format it):

```
local function DofileIntoEnv(filename, env)
    setmetatable ( env, { __index = _G } )
    local status, result = assert(pcall(setfenv(assert(loadfile(filename)), env)))
    setmetatable(env, nil)
    return result
end
```

I wanted to be able to load multiple files into the same environment, and some of these files had a 'return something' in them. Thanks RBerteig, your answer was helpful and instructive!

Answer (score 0):

In Lua > 5.2

```lua
function run_test_script(scriptfile)
    local env = setmetatable({}, {__index=_G})
    assert(pcall(loadfile(scriptfile,"run_test_script",env)))
    setmetatable(env, nil)
    return env
end
```

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.