# Loading a file and returning its environment

Tags: lua, env, lua-5.2, lua-loadfile

I'm attempting to do the following : (include() code below)

File1.lua

```
A = 5
```

File2.lua

```
file1 = include(File1.lua)
A = 1

print(A) -- 1
print(file1.A) -- 5
```

i've found exactly what i'm looking for but in lua 5.1 here : 
[Loadfile without polluting global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540732/lua-loadfile-without-polluting-global-environment?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But i just can't get it to work in 5.2,

```
function include(scriptfile)
local env = setmetatable({}, {__index=_G})
assert(pcall(setfenv(assert(loadfile(scriptfile)), env)))
setmetatable(env, nil)
return env 
end
```

Using this from C++, with a registered version of loadfile, so i'm trying not to modify the function call.Is this possible?
Whatever i try breaks or env is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File2.lua

```
function include(scriptfile)
    local env = setmetatable({}, {__index=_G})
    assert(loadfile(scriptfile, 't', env))()
    return setmetatable(env, nil)
end

file1 = include'File1.lua'
A = 1

print(A)       -- 1
print(file1.A) -- 5
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think any solution like this would work because i was using my own version of loadfile, but my understanding of how it was wrapped was wrong...

Comment: asserting pcall doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I can see what daurnimator means. If you intend for ill-formed scripts to fail, why not just call it regularly instead of going through the whole `assert(pcall` business?